# Do I need to install another virtualbox for genymotion?

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

So I have Android Studios in a virtual box running mint. Do I need to install virtualbox to run genymotion in the original virtualbox or is there a work around? As of right now when I install genymotion it tells me it couldn't find the path of the virtualbox, which makes sense since it is in the virtualbox. Anyone else try and succeed at doing this?

Thanks

Comment: ofcourse it needs another virtual box. Think of it as you are running mint in a virtual box container, now to run the gennymotion emulators you need to install the virtual box, but this is very tideous are bad idea, it is recomended that you do a full OS install

Comment: why would this be a bad idea? Aside from it being tedious.

Comment: Your performance of the machine will be sluggish

Comment: Ah I get how that would be a problem thank you.

Comment: Would you accept the answer if i posted it as an answer ?

Comment: Yes of course, I mean I would emphasize the performance point in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it needs another virtual box. Think of it as you are running mint in a virtual box container, now to run the gennymotion emulators you need to install the virtual box, but this is very tideous are bad idea, it is recomended that you do a full OS install.

Your performance of the machine will be sluggish since you are trying to run a OS indside an OS(The resoruces wil be lesser to be used vs a fully installed OS)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Oracle VM VirtualBox

Comment: I understand that and I am my question is more like am I able to and really more like should I? @penta answers that question more or less.